# Python&VkApi - Проверка на новые сообщения

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Мне нужно сделать бота, который будет проверять есть ли непрочитанные или новые сообщения, но я не знаю как. Знаю только что можно через LongPoll, но с ним у меня проблемы выскакивают. Можно ли как то по другому?

Comment: какого рода "проблемы выскакивают через LongPoll" ?

Comment: Не могу его использовать, пишет No access

Comment: у вас получены credentials от ВК?

Comment: аээ, а это что?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs?f=1.1.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0

Comment: а у меня обычная страница, не бот

Comment: Может тогда вам подойдёт User long poll api?

Comment: @D.Violet именно его я и использую, делаю все по инструкции на сайте, и когда создаю объект longpool пишет No access.